# How can I pull a filename using when using a command line/OS in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull a filename from the command line using OS in python.
I'm searching for a file that's created at a specific time.
While I can get the result I want, I can't do anything with what I get.
Here' my code:

```
import os

file = str(os.system('ls -ltr | grep fileName | grep 09:29 | head -1'))
```

The result is:

```
-rw-r--r-- l dir dir         126649 Jun 14 09:29 fileName.011
```

However, when I try to strip out just the file name, I just get the whole line.
I've tried using `file[-11:]` without success.
I've confirmed the type of the result is a string:
`<type 'str'>`
I've tried adding the result to a list and then splitting it, but that didn't work either.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: os.system() doesn't return that line - look at the documentation for os.system all it returns is the return code (i.e. an number - normally 0 for success).

Answer (score 2):

[`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) does not return the output from the shell.

Use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for that

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('ls -ltr | grep fileName | grep 09:29 | head -1', shell=True))
```

And then you can slice your filename from `output`.